# Mysql two table join where second table with unique records and last entry for each

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with what seems to be a simple task. I have two tables in my database:

```
Table devices:
id, uid, devicecode, devicename, devicetype

Table devicelogs:
id, devicecode, timelogged, devicestatus
```

Before my page loads, I get all the user's devices with the following query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE `uid`='1'";
```

This gets me all the user's devices which I then use to create 'switches' on the page using checkboxes.

To set the checkbox's status, I need to then check what the last devicestatus of that device was in the 'devicelogs' table (on or off).

I am guessing I would have to do a join of some sort where the devicelogs table should show the last records of each of the devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your query in two steps. First of all, you get the latest `timelogged` for each `devicecode`

```
select  devicecode, max(timelogged) as max_timelogged
from    devicelogs
group by devicecode
```

The you can use the above query as a filter, by joinig it with the original tables

```
select  t1.*, t2.timelogged, t2.devicestatus
from    devices t1
join    devicelogs t2
on      t1.devicecode = t2.devicecode
join    (
            select  devicecode, max(timelogged) as max_timelogged
            from    devicelogs
            group by devicecode
        ) t3
on      t2.devicecode = t3.devicecode and
        t2.timelogged = t3.max_timelogged
```

Comment: Getting the record with max value type of questions are asked pretty much every day. Pls mark them as duplicate rather than try to answer each question separately.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, I understand the concept now! I appreciate it.